# Hibernate inheritance without table for basic entity

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I've never used inheritance in hibernate and I don't know which strategy should I use (or even do I really need to use strategy). I have three tables with the same interface (the same columns) and I want to create three entities with basic interface for them so it will look like this:

```
  @Entity
+ Basic

    + @Entity
      @Table(name="TABLE_1")
      Table1

    + @Entity
      @Table(name="TABLE_2")
      Table2

    + @Entity
      @Table(name="TABLE_3")
      Table3
```

As you see I don't want to use table for basic entity. If it is possible to do this kind of inheritance, how to do it? Maybe I don't need 'hibernate' inheritance and I should use normal inheritance?

In application it is used like this:

1. Somewhere in configuration we store information which entity to use (Table1, Table12 or Table3)
2. Choosen entity is used in our queries (some writen in HQL, some in Criteria) so each query should know which entity to use.

**EDIT**

What's more each entity can be used as attribute of some entities and we wan't to know which table should be used. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Basic basicEntity; // how to use proper strategy using some configuration value (eg. class static attribute or configuration value stored in db?)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is recommended way of achieving your goal:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    public static final int SHARED_PAREMETER = 2;

    @Column(name = "modified", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()")
    protected Date modified;

    //... other fields, getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_1")
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Table2 table2;  
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_2")
public class Table2 {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

In this case, we will have only two tables but both would have fields from BaseEntity. You can't, though, make a relation in Entity to an abstract class but in processing you're fully entitled to do something like this:

```
public void process(BaseEntity entity){
   // processing..
}
```